# LaTeX3, l3keys: Combining .choice and .default

Tags: expl3

With LaTeX3 and `l3keys` (included in `expl3`), is there a way to have a *choice* that includes a default value (or an empty choice)?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {test}
  {
    font .choice:,
    font / sf .code:n = {},
    font .default:n = {},
  }
\keys_set:nn { test } { font= }  % ERROR
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.default:n` part is for supplying a value when no `=` follows the key.

You can of course define an empty choice, if you want, and assign it also as the default value.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {test}
  {
    font .choice:,
    font / sf .code:n = {sf},
    font / bf .code:n = {bf},
    font /  .code:n = {empty},
    font .default:n = {},
  }
\keys_set:nn { test } { font }
\par
\keys_set:nn { test } { font= }
\par
\keys_set:nn { test } { font=bf }
\end{document}
```

This will print

[image]